# How to override the square extension on the checkout page?

Tags: checkout, overrides, payment-methods

Im trying to customize the

> public_html/vendor/square/module-squareup-omni/view/frontend/web/template/payment/square.html

I made override, but it doesn't work

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Square_Connect/web/template/payment/square.html

I cleared the cache and dicompiled, it didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

if module name module-squareup-omni  then  it will be displayed as Square_SquareupOmni

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Square_SquareupOmni/web/template/payment/square.html
```